# Outputting custom data type to file

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, hpc

Given a struct `Pixel` and its equivalent `MPI_Type mpiPixel` i create an array of pixels and write it to a file. Everything runs correctly except, the output in the file ends in some sort of a bit pattern (being interpreted as integers). The file is outputted in binary thus to view it was written correctly i use `hexdump -v -e '7/4 "%10d "' -e '"\n"' pixelsx`

THE CODE

```
struct Pixel
{
    int red; int green; int blue;

    Pixel() {}

    Pixel(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        red = r; green = g; blue = b;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rank, size;
    MPI_File   file;
    MPI_Offset offset;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Datatype mpiPixel;

    Pixel pixels[10];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    /* fill local data */
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        pixels[i] = Pixel(i, i, i);

    int blockcounts[1];
    MPI_Aint offsets[1];
    MPI_Datatype oldtypes[1];

    //Pixel Description {starting pos, element count, element type}
    offsets[0] = 0;
    blockcounts[0] = 3;
    oldtypes[0] = MPI_INT;

    /* Now define structured type and commit it */
    MPI_Type_struct(1, blockcounts, offsets, oldtypes, &mpiPixel);
    MPI_Type_commit(&mpiPixel);

    /* open the file, and set the view */
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "pixels",
                  MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY,
                  MPI_INFO_NULL, &file);

    MPI_File_seek(file, 0, MPI_SEEK_SET);
    MPI_File_set_view(file, 0,  MPI_CHAR, mpiPixel, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
    MPI_File_write_all(file, pixels, 10, mpiPixel, &status);
    MPI_File_close(&file);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

THE OUTPUT

```
     0          0          0          1          1          1          2
     2          2          3          3          3          4          4
     4          5          5          5          6          6          6
     7          7          7          8          8          8          9
     9          9    4228656          0          0          0    4228656
     0          0          0 -1795965243      32585
```

The line which shouldn't be there (if i'm not mistaken) is

```
4228656          0          0          0    4228656         0          0          0 -1795965243      32585
```

Why is the latter printed in the file. It is a memory assignment issue (the array?)?

P.s. The code is run with only one process. The reason is that i first need to get the write function working. Then ill add the offset for the other processes

Comment: so, what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

The MPI datatype does not correspond to the C++ structure at all. Your `Pixel` structure consists of three `int` elements. You register an MPI datatype for four `float` elements and use it to write the array of structures to the file. Since `int` and `float` happen to be of the same size on most 32- and 64-bit architectures and since no padding is added between the structure elements, MPI ends up reading `(4*sizeof(float) - sizeof(Pixel))*10 = 40` bytes past the end of the `pixels` array. This shows up as 10 (40/4) additional random values in the file content.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that i posted an old rendition of the code... But alas i myself noticed it - changed it - and still the same results. Regardless ill fix the post.